# Cannot load installer CD on Acer Aspire TC605 (keep restarting)

Tags: installation, lubuntu, acer

I've tried installing Windows XP with no problem.

I'm going to install Lubuntu 13.10
When boot Lubuntu 13.10 CD, computer keep reboot and stuck in reboot loop.

It looks like the computer reboot once it read the CD contents.

I've lots of Lubuntu release (10.10, 11.04, etc). I've tried all them and the result are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's not your problem, but the laptop's.

Download Xubuntu from Xubuntu.org instead and see if Xubuntu will work with your laptop; many laptops won't work with one variety of Ubuntu but will with others.

Comment: Xubuntu & Kubuntu gives error: `(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system`

Comment: solved. Install using USB drive run without problem

Comment: Maybe the CD-R was burned but not closed, or burned for packet writing instead of mastered. Only closed, mastered discs are bootable.